# Insurance for Mexican-plated vehicle in the US

Tags: car, insurance, vehicle-registration, car-insurance

I'm a visa holder. My plan is to be around 1,000 miles from the border for a period of 12 to 18 months (Currently on month 4). I brought my Mexican-plated vehicle, since I used to live near the border. I renewed my insurance a couple of days ago and realized it says that I'm not covered if I don't reside in Mexico.

- The vehicle is under my name.
- The vehicle is up to date with permits.
- My foreign driver's license is valid.

What is the process to have my Mexican-plated vehicle insured in the U.S. as a non-citizen/non-immigrant visa holder?

PS. If my stay is prolonged by the employer, I plan to get a U.S. vehicle. My question is for the *current term*.

Comment: In most states you're not allowed to drive with an out of state license after living in the state for a certain period that I think is usually from one to three months in duration.  So really you ought to register your car in your state of residence, in which case insurance won't be complicated.

Comment: Vehicle isn't US tho... @phoog

Comment: Then perhaps you should read up on the requirements for importing vehicles into the US.  If your car doesn't meet the requirements then you can either have it modified to comply or sell it and buy one that complies (for example, one made for the US market).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its been 3 years since I posted my question so I guess I ought to answer it myself now.

Short answer: Yes, there are services that will insure your foreign vehicle in the US under the limits of the state you're residing in. The downside is that your premium will very high and most services will only insure you for basic coverage. So unless you plan to make your stay/ownership of vehicle temporary, I do not recommend doing this, since it is not cost effective.